# Find the accumulation points of $A = \{ (x,y) : y=0 \}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Find the accumulation points $A^\prime$ of $A = \{ (x,y) : y=0 \}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

**My attempt:**

Take any $p \in \mathbb{R}$ $\implies (p,0) \in A$. Now we can see $\forall r > 0, B^\prime ((p,0),r)\cap A \neq \emptyset \implies (p,0) \in A^\prime \implies A \in A^\prime$

Now take any point $(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2, b \neq 0$. We can clearly find at least one $r>0$ such that $B^\prime ((a,b),r) \cap A = \emptyset \implies (a,b) \not\in A^\prime$.

We have thus shown that $A^\prime = A$

Comment: I believe the answer is $A'=\mathbb{R}$. You could also do it using sequences.

Comment: @Poppy - So my answer is correct? LOL! It just seemed very wrong for some reason (I'm doing some late night mathematics)

Comment: Yes :) Every point in $A$ is it's accumulation point.

Comment: Your answer should read $A'=A.$ Note that $\mathbb{R}$ is not a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2,$ although you may be identifying $A$ with $\mathbb{R}.$ In the second part of your argument you need to point $b\ne 0.$

Comment: Yes, what @mfl said.